# On the lengths of the cycles of random permutations

Tags: probability

A random permutation of $n$ from $n$ is chosen. What is the mathematical expectation of the sum of squares of lengths of its cycles?

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: @Did: I don't see any approach to find it.

Comment: This cannot be: what is the answer for $n=1$, $n=2$, $n=3$? And for $n=4$?

Comment: @Did: Of course, a mathematical experiment is useful. But the cases $n=1, n=2, n=3$ are not helpful in cosideration of the case, say, $n=20$.

Comment: How do you know?

Comment: @Did: I have just tried the cases $n=1$ and $n=2$.

Comment: Listen, it is impossible to fail to have an idea of the result for every $n$ if one writes down the solution for every $n\leqslant4$, and difficult if one writes down the solution for every $n\leqslant3$. The rest is your choice.

Comment: 90% of the time, the sum of the squares of something turns out to be the square of something else. Pythagoras is everywhere. Like others have said, I would try a few cases by hand (actually I would do it on a computer), and look at both the patterns in the cycles and the sum of squares itself. Then I would look at how these numbers differed from perfect squares. If they are perfect squares, you are well on your way.

Comment: Perhaps you could give the values you do know ...

Answer (score 6):

Let $[n]=\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$. Let us compute the distribution of the length $\ell$ of the cycle passing by $1$ in a random permutation $s$ uniformly distributed in $\mathfrak S_n$.

If $s(1)=1$, then $\ell=1$. This happens with probability $\frac1n$. Conditionally on $s(1)\ne1$, one can assume without loss of generality that $s(1)=2$. Then $\ell=2$ if $s(2)=1$. This happens with conditional probability $\frac1{n-1}$ since $s(2)$ can be any number in $[n]\setminus\{2\}$. Thus $\ell=2$ with unconditional probability $\left(1-\frac1n\right)\cdot\frac1{n-1}=\frac1n$. Iterating this reasoning, one sees that $\ell=i$ with probability $\frac1n$ for every $i$, that is, that $\ell$ is uniformly distributed on $[n]$.

Once the cycle passing by $1$ is determined, the rest of $s$ is a permutation on the complement of this cycle in $[n]$, that is, a permutation a set with $n-\ell$ elements.
Thus, the sum $S_n$ of the squares of the lengths of the cycles of a permutation uniformly distributed in $\mathfrak S_n$ is such that
$$
S_n\stackrel{\mathrm{dist.}}{=}\ell^2+S_{n-\ell},
$$
where $\ell$ is uniformly distributed on $[n]$, with the convention that $S_0=0$. In particular,
$$
E[S_n]=\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^n\left(k^2+E[S_{n-k}]\right)=\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^nk^2+\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}E[S_{k}].
$$
One can solve this recursion in a elementary way, noting that
$$
nE[S_n]=\sum_{k=1}^nk^2+\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}E[S_{k}],
$$
hence
$$
nE[S_n]-(n-1)E[S_{n-1}]=n^2+E[S_{n-1}],
$$
that is,
$$
E[S_n]=n+E[S_{n-1}],
$$
and finally,
$$
E[S_n]=\sum_{k=1}^nk=\frac{n(n+1)}2.
$$

Comment: The (a priori surprising) key fact that the length of the cycle passing by 1 is uniformly distributed can be "discovered" thanks to the explicit computations of some small $n$ cases which were suggested in the comments. Unfortunately this suggestion seems to have been met by the OP with some amount of skepticism.

Comment: I find your deep answer excellent and vote up. Can you kindly clarify the following? Up to Wiki [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation) ,
"The size l of the orbit is called the length of the cycle" ,"An orbit of size 1 (a fixed point $x$ in S) has no corresponding cycle, 
since that permutation would fix $x$ as well as every other element of $S$, in other words it would be the identity, independently of $x$".
But (as far as I understand it) you take into account such cycles.

Comment: Yes, in my answer, fixed points are called cycles of length `1`.

Comment: this is so hard to understand but looks so good

Answer (score 3):

The exponential generating function of permutations by the sum of the squares of the lengths of its cycles is
$$ G(z, u) = 
\exp
\left(u z + \frac{1}{2} u^4 z^2 + \frac{1}{3} u^9 z^3 + \frac{1}{4} u^{16} z^4 \cdots\right)$$
which means that the probability generating function of the expectation that we are looking for is
$$ \left.\frac{\partial}{\partial u} G(z, u) \right|_{u=1} \\= 
\left.
\exp
\left(u z + \frac{1}{2} u^4 z^2 + \frac{1}{3} u^9 z^3 + \frac{1}{4} u^{16} z^4 \cdots\right)
\left(z + 2 u^3 z^2 + 3 u^8 z^3 + 4 u^{15} z^4 \cdots\right)
\right|_{u=1} \\=
\exp\log\frac{1}{1-z}\times \frac{z}{(1-z)^2} = 
\frac{1}{1-z}\times \frac{z}{(1-z)^2} =
\frac{z}{(1-z)^3}.$$

The conclusion is that the expectation we are trying to compute is given by
$$[z^n]  \left.\frac{\partial}{\partial u} G(z, u) \right|_{u=1} =
[z^n] \frac{z}{(1-z)^3} = \frac{1}{2} n (n+1).$$

Comment: Can you kindly give a reference to the generating function?

Comment: I constructed this function in response to your particular query. There is more on the method at [Symbolic Combinatorics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_combinatorics) and the class/type of generating function is discussed at [Random Permutation Statistics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_permutation_statistics).